# Android: send post data to django rest framework

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework

I write an app with django and android. I have written the backend in django and now i want to write client in android. Now i don't know how i can send post data to my django rest webservice.  please can you help me. thank you.  sorry if i have mistake, my english level is low.

Comment: use retrofit: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: thank for your answer @kelvincer. is what retrofit is good in terms of performance?

Comment: please @kelvincer can you give me an explicit example of retrofit use ? because i'm not understand why it work. thank again

Answer (score 1):

Client interface:

```
public interface SimpleApi {

    public static final String PATH = "/path";

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(PATH)
    public void updateUser(@Field("first_name") String first, @Field("last_name") String last, Callback<Boolean> callback);
}
```

Make your request (Asynchronous execution):

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://www.apiurl.com")
        .build();

SimpleApi service = restAdapter.create(SimpleApi.class);

service.updateUser(firstName, lastName, new Callback<User>() {

     @Override
     public void success(Boolean aBoolean, Response response) {

         Log.i(TAG, "Succesfull");

     @Override
     public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

         Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());

     }
});
```